# Why doesn't the WCF service method have its parameter set to the correct value

Tags: c#, wcf

If I have a WCF service that contains a method that looks like this...

```
  [OperationContract]
  public void Jim(int ID) {
    // DO SOMETHING HERE
  }
```

...and I use this method in a client, all works fine.

If I subsequently rename the service method's parameter to `id` then when the service method is called, the parameter is not set, so has the value zero.

If I then regenerate the service reference in the client, the parameter gets set correctly.

What I don't understand is why this partially worked. I would have expected it to work completely (ie have the parameter set to the correct value), or to fail with an exception.

If the incoming request was recognised as the same method, then it should have recognised the parameter name and set the value. If it didn't match the parameter names, then it should have been seen as a different method, and thrown an exception that the method it wanted was missing. I don't understand why it called the right method, but not set the parameter value.

Anyone able to explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a SOAP service, the parameter name will actually be included in the XSD generated for the operation.  This means that unless you update the client's service reference, it's definition of the operation will still contain the old parameter name.  When WCF goes to serialize the value across the wire from the client to the server, the parameter value from the client will not be properly serialized because of the name mismatch.

Think of it this way:

The client, based on its service reference packages up the operation and parameter into an XML document that it then in turn sends up to the server as a request. This is serialization.

The server, based on it's service reference now needs to unpackage the XML for the request and figure out what to do.  It unwraps the operation and compares it to its list of known operations in its service reference; it sees that you are requesting an operation named `Jim` which takes one string parameter.  It then looks at any/all parameter values for that operation in the XML document for any passed values.  This is deserialization.  In your case, the client passed the parameter with a different name value than what the service is expecting. It will not be able to find the value in the XML and will not set the value.

In order for things to work properly, the client and the service have to agree and match on the service reference definition.

[This](http://www.diranieh.com/NET_WCF/Serialization.htm) describes WCF Data Contracts and the Serialization and is worth a read.

Comment: @codechum Thanks, but based on that (which is actually what I would have expected to happen), I would have thought that the method with the parameter named `id` would have been seen as a different method from the one with the parameter named `ID` meaning that I would have got a missing method exception. I don't understand how it matched the method but didn't match the parameter.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel you will not get a missing method exception.  The parameter values of the method are just part of the message.  You're client's definition of the method says that the parameter name is `id`; your server says the parameter name is `ID`.  When the client invokes the server `Jim` operation, it will pass along the `id=1`; however when the server looks at the message, it will explicitly be looking for `ID=<some value>` notice the case difference.

Comment: @codechum Thanks for the explanation. Still seems a bit odd to me, but I think I see why it works that way. I would have thought they would have done it differently, but they didn't ask me! At least I know what happened now.